# mpi4py MPI.init() hangs indefinitely

Tags: macos, python

I am trying to initialise MPI in python (3.7.0) using the MPI module in mpi4py, but it hangs indefinitely when I try the following:

```
mpirun -n 4 python -c "from mpi4py import MPI"
```

This works:

```
python -c "from mpi4py import MPI"
```

but this doesn't:

```
mpirun -n 1 python -c "from mpi4py import MPI"
```

I also tried

```
import mpi4py
mpi4py.rc.initialize = False
from mpi4py import MPI
MPI.Init()
```

but it hangs at the MPI.Init() step when executed with mpirun.

My mpirun version is 1.10.7, mpi4py version is 3.0.1, and I am using macOS Mojave (10.14.3).

Edit (in response to @jcgiret):

I also tried the following:

```
mpirun -n 4 python -c "print('Before'); from mpi4py import MPI; print('After')"
```

only to get

```
Before
Before
Before
Before
```

as output

Comment: Have you tried using mpirun on a dummy command such as ls? Does mpirun -n 2 ls hang? Also, could you try with -np instead of -n?

Comment: I think the following clarifies the problem. The output of this code
```
mpirun -n 4 python -c "print('Before'); from mpi4py import MPI; print('After')"
```
is
```
Before
Before
Before
Before
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by installing Miniconda and using the conda-forge version (3.0.1) of the package:

```
conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py
```

Note: It still wouldn't work with the anaconda version (2.0.0)